# Replacing a / character in a variable in R

Tags: r, character, gsub

I have a column of a few thousand prison facility names that have been scraped from the internet, some of which contain a "/" character. I'm running a ggplot loop that plots COVID infections in each facility, but the ggsave() function breaks whenever it hits a facility with the / because it thinks I am changing the file directory. 
Is there a way to change the "/" character in my column to a "-"? I tried using gsub() but to no avail: 
(1)

```
fix$Name <- gsub("\/"","-",gsub$Name)
```

I get the following error (2)

```
Error in gsub$Name : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I initially tried to just run (3)

```
fix$Name <- gsub("/","-",gsub$Name)
```

But I am fairly sure that I need an escape character, hence code line (1).

fix$Name is a character string.

If anyone has an insight that would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: you also need to escape the backslash.. hence `\\/` should work

Comment: @Wimpel thanks! I tried `fix$Name <- gsub("\\/"","-",gsub$Name)` but it is giving me the same error. Am I doing it wrong? Sorry for being dense! I appreciate the help!

Comment: try `gsub("\\/","-",gsub$Name)`